# for...in if not null or undefined

Tags: coffeescript

In my Javascript code, I process many json objects with properties that may be null:

```
if (store.departments != null) {
    for(var i = 0; i < store.departments.length; i++) {
        alert(department.name);
    }
}
```

In porting my app to coffeescript, I came up with the following shortcut using the existential operator:

```
for department in store.departments ? []
    alert department.name
```

Is this acceptable coffeescript? Is there any scenario in which this would not work as intended?

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
if store.departments  
  alert department.name for department in store.departments
```

Or

```
alert department.name for department in store.departments if store.departments
```

Both statements compile to:

```
var department, _i, _len, _ref;

if (store.departments) {
  _ref = store.departments;
  for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    department = _ref[_i];
    alert(department.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a difference between `if store.departments` and `if store.departments?` ?

Comment: also, `alert department.name` is for arguments sake only - the actual app has a whole block of processing code

Comment: @trebuchet Yes, there is a difference - the existential operator explicitly checks for null/undefined, so falsy values like `""` will return true (`""? == true` even though `!!"" == false`).  It also shields from errors about undefined variables (`x?` will not throw an error even if `x` is undefined).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what your'e asking, this code doesn't do what you're thinking.

```
for department in store.departments ? []
```

It looks like you're using the existential operator `?` similar to how you would a ternary operator `a?b:c`.
From coffeescript.org:

> It's a little difficult to check for the existence of a variable in JavaScript. if (variable) ... comes close, but fails for zero, the empty string, and false. CoffeeScript's existential operator ? returns true unless a variable is null or undefined, which makes it analogous to Ruby's nil?

If I wanted to later use the names, I'd write something like:

```
if store.departments?
    names = (department.name for department in store.departments)
```

You could put it all on one line, but with a list comprehension, that becomes pretty unreadable. The existential operator will test null && undef and only return true if it really exists.

If you want to use a ternary operator in coffeescript, it's less terse:

```
for department in if store.departments? then store.departments else []
```

Maybe not exactly what you want, because it's extraordinarily verbose here.